# com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException getting this error

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, tomcat

I am trying to start the tomcat server and getting error that the war file is not found.
below is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly('jakarta.json.bind:jakarta.json.bind-api:3.0.0')
    compileOnly('jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.1.1')
    compileOnly('jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:5.0.0')
    implementation('org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:3.1.1')
    implementation('org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:3.1.1')
    implementation('org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:3.1.1')
    implementation('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33')

    // For JSON serialization/deserialization
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.1')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.1')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.1')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.15.1')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.1')

    // For viewing the database using a JSP
    implementation('jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:3.0.0')
    implementation('org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.1')

    // JAX-B dependencies for JDK 9+
    implementation('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1')
    implementation('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11')
    implementation('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11')
    implementation('javax.activation:activation:1.1.1')

    // For testing
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

below is the log of the error

```
[2023-09-27 11:47:30,618] Artifact Gradle : com.example : visruthaBookrestStore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.076 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.80
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 23 2023 21:59:38 UTC
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.80.0
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            13.4.1
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          aarch64
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Users/saireshma/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-19.0.2/Contents/Home
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           19.0.2+7-FR
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Amazon.com Inc.
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/saireshma/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/tomcat/5e84bca2-6e2d-41f2-b197-6654d21ab253
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/homebrew/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.80/libexec
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/saireshma/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/tomcat/5e84bca2-6e2d-41f2-b197-6654d21ab253/conf/logging.properties
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/Users/saireshma/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/tomcat/5e84bca2-6e2d-41f2-b197-6654d21ab253/jmxremote.password
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/Users/saireshma/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/tomcat/5e84bca2-6e2d-41f2-b197-6654d21ab253/jmxremote.access
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/saireshma/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/tomcat/5e84bca2-6e2d-41f2-b197-6654d21ab253
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.80/libexec
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.80/libexec/temp
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/saireshma/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.274 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [287] milliseconds
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.316 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.316 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.80]
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.329 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Sep-2023 11:47:31.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [46] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2023-09-27 11:47:31,779] Artifact Gradle : com.example : visruthaBookrestStore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2023-09-27 11:47:31,793] Artifact Gradle : com.example : visruthaBookrestStore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2023-09-27 11:47:31,794] Artifact Gradle : com.example : visruthaBookrestStore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: /Users/saireshma/IdeaProjects/visruthaBookrestStore/build/libs/visruthaBookrestStore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war not found for the web module.
27-Sep-2023 11:47:41.339 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.80/libexec/webapps/manager]
27-Sep-2023 11:47:41.482 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.80/libexec/webapps/manager] has finished in [144] ms
```

I am adding the screenshot of the directory and tomcat configuration[image]

I think from the log tomcat is looking for visruthaBookrestStore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war file but visruthaBookrestStore.war file is being generated in the builds. I dont know how to resolve it please help me.